# Pylearn2: MLP model with my own data

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, regression, pylearn

I'm trying to build an MLP model using pylearn2. But the manual isn't that explicit on how to import extern data (all tutorials use the MNSIT datas).

So, my data are CSV files:

```
0 0.129 -0.234 0.394 ... 
0 0.293 -0.394 0.234 ... 
1 0.192 -0.842 0.123 ...
...
```

So it's a matrix, the first column is the value to predict and the other columns are the attributes. I don't even know if it's the right input.

Here is my YAML file:

```
!obj:pylearn2.train.Train {
    dataset: &train !obj:pylearn2.datasets.csv_dataset.CSVDataset {
        path: 'train.csv',
        task: 'regression',
        start: 0,
        stop: 53607,
        expect_headers: False,
        num_outputs: 1
    },
    model: !obj:pylearn2.models.mlp.MLP {
        layers : [
            !obj:pylearn2.models.mlp.Sigmoid {
                layer_name: 'h0',
                dim: 10,
                irange: .05
            },
            !obj:pylearn2.models.mlp.Softmax {
                layer_name: 'y',
                n_classes: 2,
                irange: 0.
            },
        ],
        nvis: 220,
    },
    algorithm: !obj:pylearn2.training_algorithms.bgd.BGD {
        batch_size: 1024,
        conjugate: 1,
        updates_per_batch: 10,
        monitoring_dataset:
            {
                'train' : *train,
                'valid' : !obj:pylearn2.datasets.csv_dataset.CSVDataset {
                    path: 'test.csv',
                    task: 'regression',
                    start: 0,
                    stop: 17868,
                    expect_headers: False,
                }
            },
        termination_criterion: !obj:pylearn2.termination_criteria.And {
            criteria: [
                !obj:pylearn2.termination_criteria.MonitorBased {
                    channel_name: "valid_y_misclass"
                },
                !obj:pylearn2.termination_criteria.EpochCounter {
                    max_epochs: 10000
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    extensions: [
        !obj:pylearn2.train_extensions.best_params.MonitorBasedSaveBest {
             channel_name: 'valid_y_missclass',
             save_path: "best.pkl"
        },
    ],
}
```

So, there are two classes, but it says that the task is a regression if you have a matrix and not a vector.

Here is the output error when I run "train.py training.yaml"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 261, in <module>
    args.verbose_logging, args.debug)
  File "train.py", line 206, in train
    train_obj = serial.load_train_file(config)
  File "/home/romain/Projet/long/pylearn2/pylearn2/utils/serial.py", line 430, in load_train_file
    return yaml_parse.load_path(config_file_path, environ=environ)
  File "/home/romain/Projet/long/pylearn2/pylearn2/config/yaml_parse.py", line 255, in load_path
    return load(content, instantiate=instantiate, environ=environ, **kwargs)
  File "/home/romain/Projet/long/pylearn2/pylearn2/config/yaml_parse.py", line 213, in load
    return _instantiate(proxy_graph)
  File "/home/romain/Projet/long/pylearn2/pylearn2/config/yaml_parse.py", line 156, in _instantiate
    return _instantiate_proxy_tuple(proxy, bindings)
  File "/home/romain/Projet/long/pylearn2/pylearn2/config/yaml_parse.py", line 121, in _instantiate_proxy_tuple
    for k, v in six.iteritems(proxy.keywords))
  File "/home/romain/Projet/long/pylearn2/pylearn2/config/yaml_parse.py", line 121, in <genexpr>
    for k, v in six.iteritems(proxy.keywords))
  File "/home/romain/Projet/long/pylearn2/pylearn2/config/yaml_parse.py", line 156, in _instantiate
    return _instantiate_proxy_tuple(proxy, bindings)
  File "/home/romain/Projet/long/pylearn2/pylearn2/config/yaml_parse.py", line 121, in _instantiate_proxy_tuple
    for k, v in six.iteritems(proxy.keywords))
  File "/home/romain/Projet/long/pylearn2/pylearn2/config/yaml_parse.py", line 121, in <genexpr>
    for k, v in six.iteritems(proxy.keywords))
  File "/home/romain/Projet/long/pylearn2/pylearn2/config/yaml_parse.py", line 161, in _instantiate
    for k, v in six.iteritems(proxy))
  File "/home/romain/Projet/long/pylearn2/pylearn2/config/yaml_parse.py", line 161, in <genexpr>
    for k, v in six.iteritems(proxy))
  File "/home/romain/Projet/long/pylearn2/pylearn2/config/yaml_parse.py", line 156, in _instantiate
    return _instantiate_proxy_tuple(proxy, bindings)
  File "/home/romain/Projet/long/pylearn2/pylearn2/config/yaml_parse.py", line 122, in _instantiate_proxy_tuple
    obj = checked_call(proxy.callable, kwargs)
  File "/home/romain/Projet/long/pylearn2/pylearn2/utils/call_check.py", line 99, in checked_call
    return to_call(**kwargs)
  File "/home/romain/Projet/long/pylearn2/pylearn2/datasets/csv_dataset.py", line 123, in __init__
    X, y = self._load_data()
  File "/home/romain/Projet/long/pylearn2/pylearn2/datasets/csv_dataset.py", line 149, in _load_data
    data = np.loadtxt(self.path, delimiter=self.delimiter)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 856, in loadtxt
    X = np.array(X, dtype)
```

I copied train.py from "pylearn/pylearn/scripts/train.py" and the CSV files are in the actual folder.

Is my YAML file wrong? I don't really get the meaning of the error.

Comment: Please be advised about the warning in [pylearn2 page](http://deeplearning.net/software/pylearn2/):
`This project does not have any current developer. We will continue to
review pull requests and merge them when appropriate, but do not
expect new development unless someone decides to work on it. There are other machine learning frameworks built on top of Theano that could interest you, such as: Blocks, Keras and Lasagne`

Comment: Ian has a post [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/02/10/pylearn2-regression-3rd-party-data/) about setting up a regression model.

Comment: And reading through [csv_dataset.py](https://github.com/lisa-lab/pylearn2/blob/master/pylearn2/datasets/csv_dataset.py) may provide some insights.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I decided to switch from pylearn to theano which is more documented (and works with GPU).

Comment: You could also give [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) a try.